# glm summary not giving coefficients values

Tags: r, logistic-regression, data-science

I'm trying to apply glm on a given dataset,but the `summary(model1)` is not giving me the correct output , it's not giving coefficient values for `Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)` etc, it's just giving me `NA` as an output for individual attribute element.

```
TEXT <- c('Learned a new concept today : metamorphic testing.  t.co/0is1IUs3aW','BMC Bioinformatics BioMed Central: Detecting novel ncRNAs by experimental #RNomics is not an easy task... http:/t.co/ui3Unxpx #bing @MyEN','BMC Bioinformatics BioMed Central: small #RNA with a regulatory function as a scientific ... Detecting novel… http:/t.co/wWHOEkR0vc #bing','True or false? link(#Addition, #Classification) http:/t.co/zMJuTFt8iq #Oxytocin','Biologists do have a sense of humor, especially computational bio people http:/t.co/wFZqaaFy')
NAME <- c('QSoft Consulting','Fabrice Leclerc','Sungsam Gong','Frederic','Zach Stednick')
SCREEN_NAME <-c ('QSoftConsulting','rnomics','sunggong','rnomics','jdwasmuth')
FOLLOWERS_COUNT <- c(734,1900,234,266,788)
RETWEET <- c(1,3,5,0,2)
FRIENDS_COUNT <-c(34,532,77,213,422)
STATUSES_COUNT <- c(234,643,899,222,226)
FAVOURITES_COUNT <- c(144,2677,445,930,254)

df <- data.frame(TEXT,NAME,SCREEN_NAME,RETWEET,FRIENDS_COUNT,STATUSES_COUNT,FAVOURITES_COUNT)
mydata<-df
mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT <- ifelse( mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT >= 445, 1, 0)  #converting fav_count to binary values
```

Splitting data

```
library(caret)
split=0.60
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- mydata[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- mydata[-trainIndex,]
```

glm model

```
library(e1071)
model1 <- glm(FAVOURITES_COUNT~.,family = binomial, data = data_train)
summary(model1)
```

I want to get the p value for further analysis so far i think my code is right, how can i get the correct output?

Comment: Try CrossValidated instead: http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you factorised the nominal variables `as.factor()`?

Comment: ok sure. no I have not done anything besides the code I have just posted. why should we use as.factor() for nominal variables?

Comment: Maybe the number of parameters (7) is more than number of observations (5), p > n? Logistic regression cant fit this data?

Comment: No, this is just sample data , my original data has about 13 parameters and above 1000 observations :/

Comment: you don't need library e1071 for glm, it's for svm

Comment: If `TEXT` and/or `SCREEN_NAME` and/or `NAME` have lots of unique values, you could have more predictor variables than observations, even with more than a thousand observations. Also, should both `NAME` and `SCREEN_NAME` be in the model (aren't they just different names for the same underlying person)? For that matter, should `TEXT`, `NAME` or `SCREEN_NAME` be in the model at all? If you have, say, hundreds or even tens of different values of `NAME` or `TEXT` in your data set, what the interpretation of all those coefficients be?

Comment: Collapsing the outcome variable, `FAVOURITES_COUNT`, down to 0 or 1 throws away information, because you lose information about how far a given `FAVOURITES_COUNT` was from the cutoff value , and that info could improve the predictions. Instead, maybe fit a gaussian family regression (i.e., classical linear regresion) instead of logistic and then apply the cutoff value to classify the predictions as "high" or "low".

Answer (score 1):

A binomial distribution will only work if the dependent variable has two outcomes. You should consider a Poisson distribution when the dependent variable is a count. See here for more details: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html

Comment: You're correct, but it looks like the OP addresses this issue with `mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT <- ifelse( mydata$FAVOURITES_COUNT >= 445, 1, 0)  #converting fav_count to binary values`

Comment: Ah sorry hadn't spotted that line. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code for fitting the GLM is programmatically correct. However, there are a few issues:

1. As mentioned in the comments, for every variable that is categorical, you should use `as.factor()` to make it into a factor. GLM doesn't know what a "string" variable is.
2. As MorganBall indicated, if your data truly is count data, you may consider fitting it using a Poisson GLM, instead of converting to binary and using Logistic regression.
3. You indicate that you have 13 parameters and 1000 observations. While this may seem like enough data, note that some of these parameters may have very few (close to 0?) observations in them. This is a problem.
4. In addition, did you make sure that your data does not [perfectly separate](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/complete_separation_logit_models.htm) the response? Because if there are some combinations of parameters that do separate the response perfectly, the maximum likelihood estimate won't converge and theoretically goes to infinity. Practically speaking, you'll get very large standard errors for your estimates.